# Html Css Bootstrap problem with text decoration

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[this is my problem pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQa5r.png)

hello , I have a problem in my project with bootstrap. When I add bootstrap with link to my project , all "a" tags get text decoration. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

you can add class="text-decoration-none" to all a tag in bootstrap

[Text Decoration bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/text/#text-decoration)